# How to rollback transaction if a sql query fails in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following method:

```java
   public void deleteProject(Project project) {
      employeeRepository.removeEmployeesFromProject(project);
      roleRepository.removeRolesFromProject(project);
      projectRepository.deleteProject(project);
   }
```

If any of the sql queries fail(unexpected exception) i would like to rollback and undo the previously done operations. So if the third query fails, i would like to undo the changes from the first two queries. Is there a way and whats the best way to do so? I read about the `@Transactional` annotation which sends all the queries in one transaction. I thought that could automatically rollback if something fails, but just annotation the method with `@Transactional` didn´t do it.

Comment: The term you're looking for is *rollback*, and yes, that's what transactions are for.

Comment: Isn´t it enough to mark the method as `@Transactional` ? Because i saw in another thread that thats the recommended solution, but it did not do the rollback for me.

Comment: Then you get to research *why* it's not working for you. Which database are you using?

Comment: I´m using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Good. I'll assume transaction management is enabled. Is `deleteProject` in a spring component class (such as `@Service`), and you're calling the method from *outside* the class, so the annotation can be detected and acted upon?

Comment: Yes, `deleteProject` is in a class marked with `@Service` and the method is directly called from another class(the controller). I will check whether manually enabling transaction management helps. But as far as i know it should be automatically enabled with spring boot on newer versions.

Comment: You might want to enable hibernate logging and pump up other logging too. The actual business logic in that method would be nicer to do as database cascades though, but that doesn't mean you don't need working transactions..

Comment: @M.Dietz Do you have something like that `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>` in your spring context initialization config file? See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Comment: @SternK he's using Spring Boot, not the outdated XML config.

Comment: @Kayaman the problem with cascades in this case is that i have a bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany relation and its mapped by the ManyToOne side. So with cascades, if i delete a project, it does a seperate query to delete each employee from the project instead of just deleting all employees from the project in one query. So i end up with n+1 queries which i avoid by writing my own custom query.

Comment: @M.Dietz I meant doing it in the database with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. There's no way you can beat that with your own custom queries.

Comment: @M.Dietz I'm just shooting in the dark but is it possible that you are already running in a larger transactional scope? Like this method gets called from another method that is already annotated with `@Transactional`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Transactions also to control rollback.

```
try{
    Transaction tx = myDAO.getDefaultPersistenceManager().
    tx.begin();
    deleteProject(project);
    tx.commit();
}finally {
    if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
        log.trace("rolling back deleting Project");
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must denote your Spring Application class with `@EnableTransactionManagement`  in order to make `@Transactional` annotations work